# Question about posessive case

Tags: possessives, poetry, attributive-nouns

What is more correct to say:

> One summer's/winter's day.

or

> One summer/winter day.

For example: "One summer('s) day we decided to walk in the park"

Answer (score 1):

Both are equally correct. The day can very much *belong* to summer, or it can just be a day *during* summer. In this case it only matters how the author wants to say it. Summer's has a way of sounding a bit more *romantic*.

Answer (score 0):

The British National Corpus (bnc) has 36 quotes for "summer day", but none for "summer's day", though "summer's day" is in dictionaries. But when "summer" is an element in compound nouns it is mostly summer: summer camp, summer house, summer school, summer time, summer vacation (AmE), summer holiday (BrE). For AmE this may be a bit different, but I don't believe that there is great difference.

Comment: I found 36 hits for "summer day" and 70 hits for "summer 's day" in BNC. Note the space before the apostrophe. Searching for words that have apostrophe inside in BYU-BNC requires a space before the apostrophe.

Comment: @Damkerng T. - Thanks for the hint. I did not know this.